# Laravel + React project not working without php artisan serve command

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel React project on localhost when I run a command

```
PHP artisan serve
```

It is working fine on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
But when I am trying to run it without php artisan serve command and trying to access with

```
http://localhost/project_name
```

It is not working. I follow all necessary changes like

1. Move .htaccess to root folder
2. server.php to index.php

Not any error just blank page

Comment: `http://localhost/project_name/public` should be the path. Why did you do those 2 things during development?

Comment: It is also not working with this url http://localhost/project_name/public
Actually development is done. Now i want to live it that's why i want to run it without php artisan serve

Comment: It won't work now because `.htaccess` is changed. By the way, is your live server Nginx or Apache?

Comment: ok the steps you took to move htaccess to the root folder and rename server.php to index.php are just wrong and whoever said that you need to do those was misleading you. To setup your project locally I highly recommend setting up a virtual host (some examples of vhost setup are [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)) and set the vhost root to be your public folder

Comment: @apokryfos I am also working on other laravel project. it is working with changing server to index and move .htaccess.
But in this scenario i am using laravel with react. laravel for api and react for frontend

Comment: i'm not saying you can't get it to work, I'm saying you must not do this. This will move your server root to your project root and make it much more likely for non-public files be exposed if you are not extremely careful. It's too much trouble to secure it given that there's a significantly easier way to set it up

Comment: @Gurpalsingh If I remember correctly, last time when I hosted a laravel project, I just pointed the domain till public folder and it worked well.